# How to handle a variable number of components with `React.forwardRef` without running afoul of hook number change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In our code, forms are wrapped in a function with some related methods (like what to do to initialise and what to do when submitting).  This resulting components contains all the form items' values in a large `state`.

Each form element is wrapped in a function allowing the wrapped form component to access these elements, such as their current value, but also when they make changes.

(It may be entirely possible that if this React app was written today (it is originally from 2016), we would have approached the forms entirely differently.  But that would be major rewrite.)

Until now, however, the form components themselves have been "dumb", i.e. they contained no logic to manipulate input.  This - however - leads to a lot of duplication of code.  The form item wrapper function, mentioned above, also takes a validation function.  But a lot of these validations are very basic, such as simply checking if the input is provided.

So I've been trying to introduce "smart" components.  However, in order to hook back into the wrapping form component, I learnt I needed to use `React.useImperativeHandle`.  This actually works.

The problem occurs, when a form is flexible, allowing the user to add more input fields on the fly.  Then React complains with `Rendered more hooks than during the previous render.`

The following is an extremely simplified version of our code:

```js
const SuffixInput = React.forwardRef(function SuffixInput(props, ref) {
  React.useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    onChange: (e) => {
      return e.currentTarget.value + 'bar'
    }
  }))

  return <input ref={ref} />
})

// in the real code, this function does a lot more, and permits options and so forth
function formItemWrapper() {
  return (child) => {
    const thisRef = React.useRef(null)
    const props = {
      // in the real code, the purpose here is to save the value of the onChange call to its place in a
      // key-value state object, but I've simplified the code out of that here
      onChange: (e) => thisRef?.current.onChange(e)
    }
    return React.cloneElement(child, props)
  }
}

function App() {
  const [elements, setElements] = React.useState([1])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {elements.map((i) => {
        return <React.Fragment key={i}>{formItemWrapper()(<SuffixInput />)}</React.Fragment>
      })}
      <button onClick={() => setElements((prev) => [...prev, prev.length+1])}>Add</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

When the user clicks the "Add" button, React immediately complains.

Is there any possible way around this, without a significant rewrite?  Like for instance being able to tell React, that's OK that the number of hooks changed.

I am willing to accept that there is not, in which case I will just have to abandon these "smart" components.

Comment: Have you tried memoizing the `formItemWrapper` function?

Comment: Considering that `formItemWrapper` is not actually a component, but rather a function that returns a React element, I am not sure it is possible to memoise it.

Comment: @Svip - You can memoize functions (function components are just functions after all, as are HOCs like your `formItemWrapper`), but I'm not immediately seeing why the suggestion is relevant here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can change your `formItemWrapper` function definition to something like this -

```js
function FormItemWrapper({ children }) {
  const thisRef = React.useRef(null)
  const props = {
    // in the real code, the purpose here is to save the value of the onChange call to its place in a
    // key-value state object, but I've simplified the code out of that here
    onChange: (e) => thisRef?.current.onChange(e)
  }
  const childWithProps = React.cloneElement(children, props);

  return <React.Fragment>{childWithProps}</React.Fragment>;
}
```

And then change the `App` component -

```js
export default function App() {
  const [elements, setElements] = React.useState([1]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {elements.map((i) => {
        return <React.Fragment key={i}>
            <FormItemWrapper>
              <SuffixInput />
            </FormItemWrapper>
          </React.Fragment>

      })}
      <button onClick={() => setElements((prev) => [...prev, prev.length + 1])}>
        Add
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This should remove the warning. Let me know if it helps!

Comment: By the way, the reason I have not accepted this answer yet is because I am currently in the progress of implementing it.  Unfortunately, our code base is a bit more complicated, and now I am having issues with it re-rendering the child element, thus an input field would lose focus.